# ORA-00905: missing keyword in a Merge statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm writing a little piece of code for an University exercise, but I can't get it to work. I want to join Impiegato and Anagrafica rows on Cod only when Anagrafica's row has no null fields. Then for each row of the new temporary table I generate a string (some_string) and this string will be the value of the Report field in ReportImpiegato table. I'm using Oracle 11g and SQL Developer. Thanks in advance to everyone willing to help. :-)

My tables are:

```
TABLE IMPIEGATO
COD NUMBER(4,0)
NOME    VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)
COGNOME VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)
DATA_ASSUNTO    DATE
STIPENDIO   NUMBER(8,2)
CAPO    NUMBER(4,0)

TABLE ANAGRAFICA
COD NUMBER(4,0)
DATAN   DATE
SESSO   CHAR(1 BYTE)
LUOGON  VARCHAR2(80 BYTE)
PROVN   CHAR(2 BYTE)

TABLE REPORTIMPIEGATO
COD NUMBER
REPORT  VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)
```

And my code is:

```
MERGE INTO ReportImpiegato R
USING (SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT *
    FROM Anagrafica A
    WHERE (A.DATAN IS NOT NULL AND A.LUOGON IS NOT NULL AND A.PROVN IS NOT NULL AND A.SESSO IS NOT NULL)) A 
    JOIN
    (Impiegato I)
    ON (A.Cod = I.Cod)
  )) D
ON (R.Cod = D.Cod)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET R.Report = some_string
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    INSERT (Cod, Report) VALUES (D.Cod, some_string)
```

Output is:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
MERGE INTO ReportImpiegato R
USING (SELECT * FROM (
        (SELECT * FROM Anagrafica A WHERE (A.DATAN IS NOT NULL AND A.LUOGON IS     NOT NULL AND A.PROVN IS NOT NULL AND A.SESSO IS NOT NULL)) A 
        JOIN
        (Impiegato I)
        ON (A.Cod = I.Cod)
      )) D
ON (R.Cod = D.Cod)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET R.Report = some_string
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    INSERT (Cod, Report) VALUES (D.Cod, some_string);
Error at Command Line : 14 Column : 5
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: On first look I would say your most inner query has no own alias name

Comment: The one after using but before on? I put the D outside the brackets to use later "ON (R.Cod = D.Cod)".

Comment: But the one after USING has another subselect in it

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: `... ON (A.Cod = I.Cod) ) X ) D`

Comment: It says a right parenthesis is missing in column 30, just before the 'X'... However the parenthesis are right, and none is missing apparently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message points to the line and character that has the issue. If I run your code as posted in the question it actually reports against (12, 5), which is the `INSERT`.

You're just missing a `THEN` on the not-matched branch:

```
...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN    --- THEN was missing!
    INSERT (Cod, Report) VALUES (D.Cod, some_string)
```

The subsequent `ORA-00904: "D"."COD": invalid identifier` is because you're doing `select *` in your `using` clause. If you run that subquery on it's own you end up with columns called `COD` and `COD_1`, at least in SQL Developer, in addition to all the other column names from both joined tables; but it's up to the client. Within the merge it seems to be doing something different. If you do

```
MERGE INTO ReportImpiegato R
USING (SELECT A.COD FROM (
```

i.e. only selecting the columns you actually need, that problem goes away.

(I don't know where `some_string` is supposed to be coming from; it may be a literal value in your real code).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice that. However it now says that "D"."COD" is an invalid identifier, ORA-00904.

Comment: @Raffolox - OK, added why you're now seeing that.

Comment: Output: 8 rows merged. Thanks, you really helped me :) Sorry for disturbing you with a relatively "noob" question but I'm learning ^^